# How to check if any element in list 1 is not present in list 2? - python

Tags: python, list, set, any

I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [1,2,3]
```

How do I go about checking if there are any elements in list1 that are not in list2?

My current code which for some reason does not work:

```
if not any(item in list1 for item in list2):
    print(True)
```

I've tried the reverse as well, but it also doesn't work:

```
if not any(item in list2 for item in list1):
    print(True)
```

So ideally I should get `True` as an output because the element 4 in list1 doesn't exist in list2, but I don't.

I'd like to know the reasoning behind why my code is incorrect as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe just use set operations: `set(list1) - set(list2)`. This will be an empty set if `list2` contains all the elements of `list1`. Alternatively: `set(list1).issubset(list2)`. If you just want to understand the logic, print the list `[item in list1 for item in list2]` and see the actual booleans involved.

Comment: Try `not all` … you can decide which way around though …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking the negative of the entire check. This will return the correct result

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [1,2,3]
if any(item not in list2 for item in list1):
    print(True)
```

The problem is that

```
any(item in list2 for item in list1)
```

Will return `True` if any item in `list2` is in `list1`, which we can agree there is. Another option is using

```
all(item in list2 for item in list1)
```

which will return `False` because not all of the `items`'s in `list1` are in `list2`. If you negate this with `not all` you will achieve the expected result.